# Prove/Disprove that $\left|\phi^{-1}(\{a\})\right| = \left|\phi^{-1}(\{b\})\right|$ for every $a, b \in f(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I encountered this statement of which I don't know if it is true or not:

Let $G, H$ be finite groups and let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from G to H. For every $a, b \in \phi(G)$ it holds true that $\left|\phi^{-1}(\{a\})\right| = \left|\phi^{-1}(\{b\})\right|$.

My question is if this is a valid statement. Furthermore how can one prove/disprove it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's true, and i think the hypotesy of finite groups is unnecessary.

If $\phi\colon G\to H$ is an homomorphism then $G/\ker \phi\cong\phi(G)$, that means that $\phi^{-1}(g)=g\ker\phi$.

So $|\phi^{-1}(g)|=|\ker\phi|=|\phi^{-1}(0)|\:\forall g\in G$